# In Florida Project, why do these characters run down to Disneyland?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-florida-project

In Florida Project (2017). in the final scene, we see child services are taking away Moonee from Halley. But she somehow escapes and runs down to Disneyland along with her friend Jancey.

How is Disneyland connected with the storyline?

Comment: Related: https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/113125/why-is-the-florida-project-named-that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Moonee lives in the Magic Castle, a motel in Kissimmee, Florida, near Walt Disney World.

Florida Project was the code name for Disney World during its construction.

Director Sean Baker said:

> [The ending is] left up to interpretation but it's not supposed to be literal, it's supposed to be a moment in which we're putting the audience in the headspace of a child.  We've been watching Moonee use her imagination and wonderment throughout the entire film to make the best of the situation she's in — she can't go to the Animal Kingdom, so she goes to the "safari" behind the motel and looks at cows, she goes to the abandoned condos because she can't go to the Haunted Mansion. And in the end, with this inevitable drama, this is me saying to the audience, 'If you want a happy ending, you're gonna have to go to that headspace of a kid because, here, that's the only way to achieve it."

It's interesting to note that the final sequence was shot "Very clandestinely" on an iPhone6 (filming in Disney World being against the rules) - the rest of the film being shot on 35mm so the change in quality is an indicator that the final sequence may not be literal.

Source: ['The Florida Project': Director Sean Baker Explains How and Why He Shot That Ending](https://www.hollywoodreporter.com/news/florida-project-ending-director-sean-baker-explains-meaning-how-he-did-it-1047215)

Comment: It's also worth noting that the movie is largely (entirely?) free of "soundtrack music" until that ending sequence, reinforcing the idea that the ending is more fantasy than literal.