# Why is "The Florida Project" named that?

Tags: title, the-florida-project

Which project is being referring to in the movie's title?

[image]

From the movie's plot, I am not sure what the "Florida Project" is meant to be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[As per Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Florida_Project):

> The title of the film refers to the initial codename for Walt Disney World during its early planning stage.

[Source](https://insidethemagic.net/2017/08/video-first-trailer-florida-project-film-highlights-life-budget-motel-near-walt-disney-world/) for that claim:

> The film’s title is a reference to Walt Disney World, which was known as “The Florida Project” during its early planning stages.